# How to see in Git all files changed in a branch type

Tags: git

When we carry out a bugfix we will use the branch naming conventiong /bugfix/{jiraKey}-{jiraTitle} and for a feature its the same but it starts with /feature/.

Is there the ability through git diff or another tool, to generate a list of all files that have been changed since a given date, only in branches that started /bugfix/?

Many thanks

Comment: heavily depends on if the branches have been merged back in, once merged back in a branch technically doesn't exist so it's hard to relocate them again.

Comment: @Ripp_24 cool so there is no way to query the name of the branch a commit came from? Assuming there isn't is there a way to get this information just for branches that currently exist.

Comment: Not in Git, no: commits do not record their original branch name. (You could enforce this as part of your standard commit *message*, if you like, but Git itself won't help other than offering you the ability to have hooks to verify things.) A commit can be on zero or more branches at any time, and typically the first few commits in a repository are on *every* branch.

Comment: The only way to work out which branch a "commit was done on" (which as @torek points out is not a thing in git) is through the commit message, either of the commit (which would make things messy) or the merge commit when the work is merged in.
If your merge commits follow a standard format, such as "merge branch <x> into <y>" then you can work out the branch from that.
I think you need to explain your use case more so we know why you need this functionality to see if there is a better way to find the info you want.